# Cannot find the file specified when batch renaming files in a single directory

Tags: python, media, rename

I've created a simple script to rename my media files that have lots of weird periods and stuff in them that I have obtained and want to organize further. My script kinda works, and I will be editing it to edit the filenames further but my os.rename line throws this error:

[Windows Error: Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.]

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    fcount = filename.count('.') - 1              #to keep the period for the file extension
    newname = filename.replace('.', ' ', fcount)
    os.rename(filename, newname)
```

Does anyone know why this might be? I have a feeling that it doesn't like me trying to rename the file without including the file path?

Comment: If the named directory is not the current directory, the names need to be prefixed with the directory before being passed to rename.

Comment: Well that was a very easy fix. thanks for your time.

        os.chdir(folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
os.rename(filename, directory + '/' + newname);
```

Answer (score 1):

Triton Man has already answered your question. If his answer doesn't work I would try using absolute paths instead of relative paths.

I've done something similar before, but in order to keep any name clashes from happening I temporarily moved all the files to a subfolder. The entire process happened so fast that in Windows Explorer I never saw the subfolder get created.

Anyhow if you're interested in looking at my script It's shown below. You run the script on the command line and you should pass in as a command-line argument the directory of the jpg files you want renamed.

Here's a script I used to rename .jpg files to multiples of 10. It might be useful to look at.

```
'''renames pictures to multiples of ten'''
import sys, os

debug=False

try:
    path = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    path = os.getcwd()

def toint(string):
    '''changes a string to a numerical representation
    string must only characters with an ordianal value between 0 and 899'''
    string = str(string)
    ret=''
    for i in string:
        ret += str(ord(i)+100) #we add 101 to make all the numbers 3 digits making it easy to seperate the numbers back out when we need to undo this operation
    assert len(ret) == 3 * len(string), 'recieved an invalid character. Characters must have a ordinal value between 0-899'
    return int(ret)

def compare_key(file):
    file = file.lower().replace('.jpg', '').replace('dscf', '')
    try:
        return int(file)
    except ValueError:
        return toint(file)

#files are temporarily placed in a folder
#to prevent clashing filenames
i = 0
files = os.listdir(path)
files = (f for f in files if f.lower().endswith('.jpg'))
files = sorted(files, key=compare_key)
for file in files:
    i += 10
    if debug: print('renaming %s to %s.jpg' % (file, i))
    os.renames(file, 'renaming/%s.jpg' % i)

for root, __, files in os.walk(path + '/renaming'):
    for file in files:
        if debug: print('moving %s to %s' % (root+'/'+file, path+'/'+file))
        os.renames(root+'/'+file, path+'/'+file)
```

Edit: I got rid of all the jpg fluff. You could use this code to rename your files. Just change the rename_file function to get rid of the extra dots. I haven't tested this code so there is a possibility that it might not work.

```
import sys, os

path = sys.argv[1]

def rename_file(file):
    return file

#files are temporarily placed in a folder
#to prevent clashing filenames
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
    os.renames(file, 'renaming/' + rename_file(file))

for root, __, files in os.walk(path + '/renaming'):
    for file in files:
        os.renames(root+'/'+file, path+'/'+file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just needed to set the default directory and it worked just fine.

```
folder = r"blah\blah\blah"    
os.chdir(folder)
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    fcount = filename.count('.') - 1
    newname = filename.replace('.', ' ', fcount)
    os.rename(filename, newname)
```

Comment: you can also use os.path.join(folder, filename) to get the full file path.